# Question about actions on a set

Tags: abstract-algebra

The following function is the permutation representation associated to the G set X
$$p: G \rightarrow Sym(X)$$

What does associated to the G set X mean?

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be group and $X$ be set.

Group action is function $f: G \times X \rightarrow X$ satisfying

1. $f(g_1g_2,x)=f(g_1,f(g_2,x))$
2. $f(e,x)=x$

Usually group action is expressed as $f(g,x)=g\cdot x$ multiplication notation
so, 1. is $(g_1g_2)\cdot x= g_1\cdot(g_2\cdot x)$ 2. is $e\cdot x =x$.

For each $g$ in $G$ , Let $\sigma _g : X \rightarrow X$ so that $\sigma _g(x)=gx$.

Then $p : G \rightarrow Sym(X)$ defined by $p(g) = \sigma_g$ is homomorphism.

If I define another group action on $X$ by $G$, $\sigma_g$ may be different because $\sigma_g(x) = gx$ depends on group action.

So, associated to $G$ on $X$ makes sense.